# Android: to display next day's date when I click the next button and to show text views from an array

Tags: java, android, string-formatting

I have a array of quotes saved in raw folder and have a next button. The first quote is displayed with today's date but when I click next button, next line quote is visible but with the same date. I need to get the next day's date to display the next quote and so on .. How can I do this?

```
//calender code
    mdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.datetext);
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    yy = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mm = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    dd = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // set current date into textview
    mdate.setText(new StringBuilder()
    // Month is 0 based, just add 1
            .append(dd).append(" ").append("-").append(mm + 1).append("-")
            .append(yy));
```

Please help me with this. Thank you soo much

Comment: why not use `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: hmm , I will use it now, but how can I get the next day's date when I click next button and also the previous day's date when I click back button?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good way to do it:

```
private static SimpleDateFormat  dateFormat  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd -MM-yyyy", Locale.US);

int dayShift = n; // Positive for next days, negative for previous days
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
if (dayShift  != 0) {
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dayShift);
}
mdate.setText(dateFormat.format(c.getTime());
```

Using DateFormat class allows you to easily change your displayed date while keeping your code the same

Comment: Thank you . Can you please look into this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829004/to-get-date-on-the-textview-and-when-clicked-next-next-date-should-appear